# Keras model.pop() not working

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, tensorflow, kaggle, keras-2

I am running Keras 2.0.6 with Python 3.6.2 and Tensorflow-gpu 1.3.0.

In order to do fine tuning on the Vgg16 model, I run this code after having hand built a vgg16 architecture and loaded the weights, but I have not called compile() yet:

```
model = self.model
model.pop()
for layer in model.layers: layer.trainable=False
model.add(Dense(num, activation='softmax'))
self.compile()
```

And when I check the graph in Tensorboard I see (check top left of attached picture) dense_3 connected to dropout_2 but dangling by itself. And then next to it I see dense_4, also connected to dropout_2.

[Tensorboard model graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DeI2.jpg)

I tried to replace pop() with the pop_layer() code below as suggested [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2640) by joelthchao on May 6, 2016. Unfortunately, the graph displayed in Tensorboard becomes an un-understandable mess.

```
def pop_layer(model):
    if not model.outputs:
        raise Exception('Sequential model cannot be popped: model is empty.')

    model.layers.pop()
    if not model.layers:
        model.outputs = []
        model.inbound_nodes = []
        model.outbound_nodes = []
    else:
        model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []
        model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
    model.built = False
```

I know something is not working right because I get low accuracy when running this on the Kaggle cats vs dog competition where I hover around 90% whilst others running this code (it's adapted from fast.ai) on top of Theanos easily get 97%. Perhaps my accuracy problem comes from somewhere else, but I still don't think dense_3 should be dangling there and I am wondering if this could be the source of my precision problem.

How can I definitely disconnect and remove dense_3?

---

See below for model.summary() before and after running the code to prepare for fine tuning. We don't see dense_3 anymore but we do see it in the tensorboard graph.

### Before Running

---

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 3, 224, 224)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_1 (ZeroPaddin (None, 3, 226, 226)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 224, 224)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_2 (ZeroPaddin (None, 64, 226, 226)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 224, 224)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 64, 112, 112)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_3 (ZeroPaddin (None, 64, 114, 114)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 112, 112)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_4 (ZeroPaddin (None, 128, 114, 114)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 112, 112)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 128, 56, 56)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_5 (ZeroPaddin (None, 128, 58, 58)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 56, 56)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_6 (ZeroPaddin (None, 256, 58, 58)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 56, 56)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_7 (ZeroPaddin (None, 256, 58, 58)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 56, 56)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 256, 28, 28)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_8 (ZeroPaddin (None, 256, 30, 30)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 512, 28, 28)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_9 (ZeroPaddin (None, 512, 30, 30)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 512, 28, 28)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_10 (ZeroPaddi (None, 512, 30, 30)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 28, 28)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 512, 14, 14)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_11 (ZeroPaddi (None, 512, 16, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 14, 14)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_12 (ZeroPaddi (None, 512, 16, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 14, 14)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_13 (ZeroPaddi (None, 512, 16, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 14, 14)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 512, 7, 7)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              4097000   
=================================================================
Total params: 138,357,544
Trainable params: 138,357,544
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

### After running

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 3, 224, 224)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_1 (ZeroPaddin (None, 3, 226, 226)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 224, 224)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_2 (ZeroPaddin (None, 64, 226, 226)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 224, 224)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 64, 112, 112)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_3 (ZeroPaddin (None, 64, 114, 114)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 112, 112)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_4 (ZeroPaddin (None, 128, 114, 114)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 112, 112)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 128, 56, 56)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_5 (ZeroPaddin (None, 128, 58, 58)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 56, 56)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_6 (ZeroPaddin (None, 256, 58, 58)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 56, 56)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_7 (ZeroPaddin (None, 256, 58, 58)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 56, 56)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 256, 28, 28)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_8 (ZeroPaddin (None, 256, 30, 30)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 512, 28, 28)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_9 (ZeroPaddin (None, 512, 30, 30)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 512, 28, 28)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_10 (ZeroPaddi (None, 512, 30, 30)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 28, 28)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 512, 14, 14)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_11 (ZeroPaddi (None, 512, 16, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 14, 14)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_12 (ZeroPaddi (None, 512, 16, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 14, 14)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_13 (ZeroPaddi (None, 512, 16, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 14, 14)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 512, 7, 7)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 8194      
=================================================================
Total params: 134,268,738
Trainable params: 8,194
Non-trainable params: 134,260,544
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a [problem](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2371) with the implimentation of layers.pop() in Keras when using the tensorflow backend. For now here is a work-around removing the last layer by name:

```
name_last_layer = str(model1.layers[-1])

model2 = Sequential()
for layer in model1.layers:
    if str(layer) != name_last_layer:
        model2.add(layer)
```

Where model1 is your original model and model2 is the same model without the last layer. In this example I've made model2 a Sequential model but you can ofcourse change this.